# Can't Access Some Tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, deadlock

I need a help that some of mysql tables are not accessable ( looks like deadlock) as my website is down and I can't open these tables through Navicat nor  phpMyAdmin , I tried to kill the query by knowing the thread ID using:

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST
```

but I didn't find any rows related to the issue.

Noting that the issue caused after I tried to run some heavy query to 2 tables which contain > 10 millions of row, and I cancelled the query after it took more than 3 hours.

I don't have access to reboot server, and I am using godaddy hosting, and they doesn't have online chatting support to my country!

Can I do anything to fix it by myside without rebooting! 
 please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is 2 million rows the query should not take 3 hours, which means the SQL itself needs serious attention. As you said  'looks like deadlock' you can examine by [**`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-engine.html)
If we get more tables in locked state then we may able to resolve these situations by setting the value of the `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` system variable.

For reference:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/glossary.html#glos_deadlock
https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/09/19/logging-deadlocks-errors/

Comment: Thanks, godaddy doesn't give me permission to use " SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS" as I am using shared hosting plan, finally I lost my tables as I reached their customer care & they didn't help me anymore !!! 
Their service is bad...

Answer (score 0):

In Unix-like OS you can use "system" or "\!" prefix to execute any command of shell inside mysql interpreter. [See this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929342/execute-shell-command-from-within-mysql-client)
Of course you must have admin privileges to run any commands in shell.

With this you can use some mysql admin command to get de PID and analise your problem by OS.