# Import XML file into MySql database with multivariable attributes

Tags: mysql, sql, xml

I am working on importing an XML file from the internet into my MySQL database and I am running into problems because it contains some multivariable attributes. For example, there may be 1 "category" tag per item or 3. In database relations, this attribute should form its own table, but I am not sure how to connect things like that. Below is a shortened example of what I am dealing with.

```
<Library>
    <Book>
        <Author> Dave </Author>
        <Title> XML Help </Title>
        <Category> Computers </Category>
        <Category> XML </Category>
    </Book>
</Library>
```

I am aware of the basic syntax as below

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'file.xml' INTO TABLE table ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Value>';
```

This assumes that there is only a single value for each attribute. I cannot edit the xml file because it is hundreds of thousands of lines long and I am looking to automate this process anyway. Thank you for your help.

Comment: have you checked the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-xml.html)

Comment: LOAD XML cannot load such file without additional processing.

Comment: Load xml can only be used to populate a single table at a time. Using the above xml file, you can create a books and a categories table through two runs , but it will not be able to populate the junction table between the two tables. You need to process the xml file with an external programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Consider transforming your XML with [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/), a declarative and special-purpose language like SQL, used specifically to transform XML documents. And since the `mysql` CLI can run [shell commands](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-commands.html) using `system` or `\!`, you can call an installed XSLT processor at command line or run a prepared (and compiled) general-purpose language (Java, Python, PHP, etc.) script at command line.

Assuming you need to transform original input to the following where distinct categories are split into different `<Book>` nodes.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Library>
   <Book>
      <Author>Dave</Author>
      <Title>XML Help</Title>
      <Category>Computers</Category>
   </Book>
   <Book>
      <Author>Dave</Author>
      <Title>XML Help</Title>
      <Category>XML</Category>
   </Book>
</Library>
```

Run below XSLT. See <kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jy6KM7f)</kbd>.

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Book">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="Category"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="Category">
     <Book>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::Author"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="preceding-sibling::Title"/>
       <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
     </Book>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="normalize-space()"/>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then, call [shell commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929342/execute-shell-command-from-within-a-mysql-client) from the `mysql` CLI:

- With Unix's xsltproc

  ```
  mysql> system xsltproc myScript.xsl Input.xml > Output.xml
  ```
- With Windows' System.Xml.Xsl (see Powershell script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42870817/14224510))

  ```
  mysql> system Powershell.exe -File "PS_Script.ps1" "Input.xml" "myScript.xsl" "Output.xml"
  ```
- Call general-purpose languages (see XSLT scripts [here](https://github.com/ParfaitG/XSLT_Transform)):

  ```
  mysql> system java run_xslt
  mysql> system python run_xslt.py
  mysql> system php run_xslt.php
  mysql> system perl run_xslt.pl
  mysql> system Rscript run_xslt.R
  ```

Finally, run `LOAD XML` using transformed document:

```sql
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'myTranformedOutput.xml' 
  INTO TABLE mytable 
  ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Book>';
```